# How do I automatically wrap text URLs in anchor tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I have a simple [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) I built for a client of mine.

This issue is, instead of him posting links probably through anchor tags, he just copies and pastes it straight into the text editor.

Is there a way that these links can be wrapped in an anchor tag using JavaScript? So when the page loads instead of it looking link this:

```
http://google.com
```

It will look like this

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">http://google.com</a>
```

Stack Overflow actually does this when a user posts a URL to an answer/question (if that helps understand what I am trying to achieve).

Comment: It's a simple string concatenation. Have you tried anything you can post here for us to look at?

Comment: I am not quite sure where to start.  I read one post here, but it seems to affect URLs within script tags and embedded tags.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168260/how-to-parse-a-url
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579335/javascript-regexp-to-wrap-urls-and-emails-in-anchors
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247479/jquery-text-to-link-script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something along these lines. Decorate the tags where you want these replacements to take effect with a custom attribute like `data-linkify`:

```html
<div data-linkify>something http://google.com something</div><div linkify>something</div>
```

Now perform replacements inside any element with `data-linkify` set.

```js
$('*[data-linkify]').each(function() { 
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(?:(https?\:\/\/[^\s]+))/m, '<a href="$1">$1</a>'));
});
```

There are some caveats. This isn’t a great regex at all — it simply matches anything starting with `http://` or `https://` up until the first whitespace character. Look for a better URL matching regex.

Also, the use of replace against `.html()` means that it will break any existing links that happen to fall under your `data-linkify` elements! If there happen to be doublequote characters in your textual links, it will create broken anchor elements.

You might consider a very simple markup of some sort to identify links — it would be much better than guessing.

Comment: I like your answere but it would be better to add the condition that would exclude urls already decorated with the a tag, it would be sufficient to add the condition for witch the string identified as url must not ends with the string "</a>"... I'm sorry I'm not able at the moment ;-)

Comment: As far as I know, jQuery doesn’t provide tools to work on Text nodes; the native DOM API does. DOM events don’t need to be broken if you replace each Text node, one by one. For example, this code appears to work quite well (in under 600 characters):

Comment: That code still has quite simple URL matching, e.g. only `http` and `https`, although it matches until it hits a space, with optional punctuation marks before it, or the end of the string, so `https://example.com/a! https://example.com/b, https://example.com/c,d,e https://example.com/f` gets parsed as `<https://example.com/a>! <https://example.com/b>, <https://example.com/c,d,e> <https://example.com/f>`.

Comment: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("body,body *")).flatMap((res) => Array.from(res.childNodes)).filter(({nodeType, parentElement}) => nodeType === Document.TEXT_NODE && !parentElement.closest("a,bb,button,details,select,textarea,option,script,noscript,style")).forEach((txt) => { const re = /\bhttps?:\/\/.+?(?=[.?!,]?(?:\s|$))/; while(re.test(txt.textContent)){ const { 0: { length }, 0: url, index: i } = txt.textContent.match(re); txt = txt.splitText(i).splitText(length); txt.previousSibling.replaceWith(Object.assign(document.createElement("a"), { href: url, textContent: url })); } });`