# Replace unlinked URL with a new link without destroying old one

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
// Convert plain text such as http, https to links.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (D) => {
    let DIVS = document.querySelector(`#ba > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.ClapLv2AnswerItem_Chie-AnswerItem__ItemText__3yFYH > div > h2,
#my_prof > div.ClapLv2MyProfile_Chie-MyProfile__Main__6htk1 > div.ClapLv2MyProfile_Chie-MyProfile__Content__2l5hM > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3)`);
    let Text = '/((https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|\/\/|https?:\/\/\r?\n)[\w?=&.\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w?&\.\/;#~%"=\+-]*>))/g';
    let change_link = '<a href="$1">$1</a>';
    for (let j = 0; j < Text.length; j++) {
        if (DIVS.innerHTML.match(Text[j])) {
            DIVS.innerHTML.replace(/((https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|\/\/|https?:\/\/\r?\n)[\w?=&.\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w\s?&.\/;#~%"=-]*>))/g, change_link);
        }
    }
});
```

For example, in the above description, you can replace the unlinked URL with a link, but if the URL is already linked, the shape of the existing link may be lost and you may not be able to successfully migrate to the link destination.  There was such a case.

`if(( DIVS.innerHTML != change_link )){`
`if(!( change_link )){`

I added the description like, and if it was already a link, I tried a process that does not convert it to a link, but it seems that conditional branching has not been possible.

How should I write it?
please tell me.

Comment: Iterate through all text nodes; don’t replace the `innerHTML`. E.g. [How do I automatically wrap text URLs in anchor tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484370/how-do-i-automatically-wrap-text-urls-in-anchor-tags/19484755#comment117786815_19484755).

Comment: Thank you for your accurate advice.
If you have solid knowledge, I would appreciate it if you could answer.