# Converting Text Link to Hyper Link and Anchor Text

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question about converting text links to hyper links. I did it successfully by using this code from this link; [How to replace plain URLs with links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
}
```

The output of this code is like;

```
Input: http://www.tinymoviez.com Output: <a href='http://www.tinymoviez.com'>http://www.tinymoviez.com</a>
```

Now what i want is to get anchor text not in link form, it should be without `'http://www.'`

In short i need the output as

```
<a href='http://www.tinymoviez.com'>tinymoviez.com</a>
```

But keep in mind that it should be auto, i will convert bulk of links at a time.

How can i do that???
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This works!!!

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w-]+\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?)/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$3</a>"); 
}
```

Input text

```
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579335/javascript-regexp-to-wrap-urls-and-emails-in-anchors";
```

Output:

```
<a href='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579335/javascript-regexp-to-wrap-urls-and-emails-in-anchors'>stackoverflow.com</a>
```

Here is a working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6e5Zm/)

Comment: Yes it works somehow, but if i have www.mywebsite.com/blabla link. Then it will Get only "www.mywebsite" Only.... :(

Comment: Can i have only website Name.... Like "Stackoverflow" only, either it have www or not.... Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: It only converts short links. With long links it give error at output. Like mywebsite.com/jhdkhdhkjhdkjhdkhdkhdkhkhdkdhkhdkhdkhkdhkjdhkjhdkhdkhdkhkdhkdhd