# Converting Text Link to Hyper Link in a Row

Tags: hyperlink

Previously i asked about [Converting Text Link to Hyper Link and Anchor Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358684/converting-text-link-to-hyper-link-and-anchor-text) and got answer. Now what i want to convert my multiple links in a Row with a Space or any sign.

Here is an example website.com | website2.com | website3.com

By using above code i am able to convert like this 1;

website.com
website2.com
website3.com

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear (at least for me) what you have and how the outcome _should_ look like?

Comment: I also personally think, that giving credits to your previous question answerer for his effort, might encourage others more to help with new questions

Comment: I edited the Post. What i want is all links should be in single row/line, instead of each link in 1 line. I hope it will make clear everything.

Comment: Is there any 1 to answer my question? Please help me if u can

Comment: If you add a `<br />` after each link, they will be lined up vertically

Comment: please read the question carefully. I want to align them horizontally. With spaces...